# Find nearest option in a Perl Hash

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a hashref that has data tied to days of the calendar year, for example:

```
 my $calendarEntries = { '1' => 'Entry 1', '5' => 'Entry 2', '15' => 'Entry 3' };
```

I can obtain the day of the year using `DateTime`:

```
state $moduleDateTime = require DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now('time_zone' => 'America/Chicago'); 
my $dayOfTheYear = $dt->strftime('%j');
```

However, I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to handle situations where the current day does not match any of the days in the hash. I'd like to always "round down" in those situations. E.g. today (which is the 7th day of the year), I'd like to load the entry with the key '5', since it is the most "recent" entry.

Is there a way to select a key in a hashref that is the closest candidate for being `<=  $dayOfTheYear`? If I were using DBD, I could do a query like this:

```
 'SELECT entry WHERE `key` <= ' . $dayOfTheYear . ' ORDER BY `key` DESC LIMIT 1'
```

But, I'd rather avoid needing to create a database and call it, if I can do something natively in Perl.

Comment: Sounds like a case for a tree, not a hash. [Tree::RB](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tree::RB) can do that sort of lookup, for example.

Comment: If all your hash keys are numbers, maybe you should use an array instead. There is no benefit to using a hash.

Answer (score 2):

One way, expecting many searches

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(last_value);

my @entries = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$calendarEntries;

my $nearest_le = last_value { $day >= $_ } @entries;
```

This returns the last element that is less or equal, for any input, so the key of interest.

The drawback of using simply a hash is that one needs an extra data structure to build.  Any library that offers this sort of lookup must do that as well, of course, but those then come with other goodies and may be considerably better performing (depending on how often this is done).

If this 'rounding' need be done *a lot* for a given hash then it makes sense to build a lookup table for days, associating each with its nearest key in the hash.<sup>†</sup> <sup>‡</sup>

If `@entries` is sorted descending (`$b <=> $a`) then the core `List::Util::first` does it.

---

<sup>†</sup> For example

```
my %nearest_le;

my @keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$calendarEntries;

for my $day (1..366) { 
    for my $k (@keys) { 
        if ($k <= $day) { 
            $nearest_le{$day} = $k; 
        }
        else { last }
    }   
};
```

This enumerates days of the year, as specified in the question.

---

<sup>‡</sup> If this were needed for things other than the days (366 at most), where long lists may be expected, a better algorithmic behavior is afforded by binary searches on sorted lists (*O(log n)*).

The library used above, [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), also has `lower_bound` with *O(log n)*

> Returns the index of the first element in LIST which does not compare *less than val*.

So this needs a few adjustments, for

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(lower_bound);

my @keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$calendarEntries;

my $nearest_le = exists $calendarEntries->{$day} 
    ? $day 
    : $keys[ -1 + lower_bound { $_ <=> $day } @keys ];
```

Comment: No need to sort to find the largest value that's less than or equal to a value.

Comment: But then it needs to compare with all elements?  (Unless one wants to place/round a `6` and finds a `5`.  But if it's a `7` to place I'll have to go through the whole list to discover that there is no `6` and that it was indeed `5`. Or am I missing something?)

Comment: Re "*But then it needs to compare with all elements?*", Yes, but only once (O(N)). Sorting requires comparing the elements more than once (O(N log N))

Comment: I mean for each rounding it needs to do O(N), while it was sorted once.  Against O(N/2) for a sorted list so it needs a good number of roundings to win but it's better algorithmically?

Comment: You're talking about doing many searches? Then what might end being best for large lists is sort + binary searches (O(log N)). For small number of values or small number of searches, the differences are probably inconsequential. (O(N/2) is just a weird way to write O(N), btw)

Comment: Yes, I'd expect that they need some sort of a lookup that may come up often.  And yes, I was just looking for some binary/lower-bound routines. Found `lower_bound` in the same module at O(logn) but it needs adjustments (it finds < not <=).  And it would take a huge number of searches for a performance gain to be felt.

Comment: As for _O_ notation, yes I know what it means -- I really meant to say that in one case we need near N comparisons every time while in the other it's N/2 on average.  Which is a real difference.  But using "O" notation was an unfortunate way to put it...

Comment: Surely the simplest way to find the nearest below existing hash entry is to start at the target, then go down until you find an existing value. You don't need to sort numerical values in a limited range.

Comment: @zdim No, it's not a real difference. N/2 elements that take 300 ns each is still going to be slower than N elements that take 100 ns each. It's surely not the case here, but you can't look at just the number of loop passes.

Comment: @ikegami "_N/2 elements that take 300 ns each is still going to be slower than N elements that take 100 ns each_" -- The N elements take 300ns each for comparison, just like the N/2 ones do ...?  That sorting was done _once_ and we are talking about timings in the lookup #1,000, long after the sorting overhead has been paid for.

Comment: [cont'd]  ... Anyway, that's what I am looking at, many many lookups.  It fetches a date, needs to bracket it into that hash, does something with it, goes on onto another.  I have applications which process years of data, day by day, for a number of different variables.  (It's typically 10-20k+ days to process.  All of a sudden even choice of a library matters! For some branches of that work I had to roll things by hand, DT and T::P were just too slow.)

Comment: I did say those numbers are not the case here.

Comment: @ikegami Wait ... I don't mean long lists to work with, I mean many repetitions for this silly 1..31 range.  But, for these out-of-1..31 numbers it probably can't be detected.  I am thinking about algorithmiics in principle.  Here it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @TLP "_Surely the simplest way to find the nearest below existing hash entry is to start at the target, then go down until you find an existing value. You don't need to sort numerical values_"  -- how's that?  If I have `5 15 1 20 31` I have to look at all of them to round `7`. And for every input number other than 6,16,2,21,20 I'll have to look at all of them.  So on average 26 comparisons.  If I have `1 5 15 20 31` I have to look at 2 of them.  (OK, `7` is a biased choice -- but for any input number it's N/2 comparisons on average.)  So I want to sort.

Comment: Why are we even talking about this?  For repeated searches sort first.  Details matter of course (how many searches? How expensive is the sort? etc), and in this case it probably doesn't matter.  But in principle it would be clear I thought?  And one may look into this page with a data list way longer than out-of-31.

Comment: Also, will elements be added? Sort using a balanced tree to reduce insertion time

Comment: @zdim TLP means: look for 7,6,5,4,3,2,1. It could be better (if most keys are present)

Comment: @ikegami  "_Sort using a balanced tree to reduce insertion time_"  -- yes, absolutely.  I'll add a comment at least (this was meant to be simple!! :)

Comment: @ikegami "_TLP means: look for 7,6,5,4,3,2,1._"   -- but that _is_ sorted!?  (It looks like I may be not getting something ...?)

Comment: @zdim The attempts are done in order, but it doesn't require sorted data. `for ($i=$target; !exists($h{$i}) && $i >= -1; --$i) { }`

Comment: @zdim I mean that you don't have to sort a range of numbers to know what order they come in. If this is days of a year, that is 1-365 (on a normal year). So we can just start at the target date and go down until we find a defined value.

Comment: OK, i see what you mean -- yes, that's a way to do this as well, fine for days in a year (in principle its worst-case behavior is bad but in this question numbers are small)

Answer (score 2):

A nice simple solution.

```perl
use List::Util qw( max );

max grep { $_ <= $dayOfTheYear } keys %$calendarEntries
```

Notes:

- Best to make sure `$calendarEntries->{ $dayOfTheYear }` doesn't exist first.
- You'll need to handle the case where there is no matching key.

It's faster than sorting unless you perform many searches. But even then, we're only dealing with at most 365 keys, so simplicity is key here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to simply look up the value for your date, and if it is not found, go down until you find a value. In this sample, I included a rudimentary error handling.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $calendarEntries = { '1' => 'Entry 1', '5' => 'Entry 2', '15' => 'Entry 3' };
my $find = shift // 7;       # for testing purposes
my $date = get_nearest_below($calendarEntries, $find);
if (defined $date) {
    say "Nearest date below to '$find' is '$date'";
} else {                     # error handling
    warn "Nearest date below not found for '$find'";
}

sub get_nearest_below {
    my ($href, $n) = @_;
    while ($n > 0) {     # valid dates are > 0
        return $n if defined $href->{$n};   # find a defined value
        $n--;            # or go to the next key below
    }
    return undef;        # or return error if nothing is found before 0
}
```

Output:

```
$ foo.pl
Nearest date below to '7' is '5'

$ foo.pl 12
Nearest date below to '12' is '5'

$ foo.pl 123
Nearest date below to '123' is '15'

$ foo.pl 0
Nearest date below not found for '0' at foo.pl line 13.
```

Comment: This would be a bad solution for a hash with keys, 1 and 1000000. But it sounds like we're only dealing with keys numbered 1..365. That means it's not a problem. (And it also means the simpler approach I posted is also not a problem even if it takes a little longer.)